# Guards on Ionic 3 components

Tags: angular, ionic2, acl, ionic3

in my Ionic 3 app I need to implement a sort of user roles check inside the specific component.

I saw that [NavController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/) implements the Angular Guards system but it seems to apply only into a view (or page) navigation scenario.

My scenario instead is made of a page (Dashboard) which contains several components and each component could be displayed depending on the specific user role.

Could you help me finding the best solution in terms of design and best practise?

Thank you so much

Comment: Unfortunately nobody answered. however, I use `ngIf` for this purpose, checking user role and then manipulating the design/view accordingly, but Im also wondering if there are other alternatives or best practices in this regard, if you've found anything regarding this, please let us know, thanx

Answer (score 3):

What you could do is create a custom directive which is placed on the component you wish to control. Something like:-

```
<my-component [custom-role-directive]="admin"></my-component>
```

The custom-role-directive checks the users role and displays or hides accordingly.